# Custom route for active admin in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to make [activeadmin](http://www.activeadmin.info/) interface to respond at a url like this

```
http://somesite.com/long_and_strange_string_of_charaters
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

I think that a website should give a 404 not found on the admin subpage.

```
http://somesite.com/admin  => 404
```

I think it is a security issue that a hacker gets a form to play with on this url.

With this in the routes.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

You get the admin interface on the /admin route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should have read even more in the documentations.

in config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
   config.default_namespace = :long_and_strange_string_of_charaters
end
```

Hope it will help someone, sometime.